# Calculating confidence intervals when binary input variable equals zero

Tags: regression, confidence-interval, binary-data, predictor

I am building a multivariate regression model and trying to use the model to predict a High, Medium, and Low estimated outcome for each individual in a group of people. I am using the 95% confidence interval to get the High/Medium/Low estimates. This means constructing a High, Medium, and Low estimate for each variable in the individual's profile, and then summing the estimates together in the appropriate category to get a High, Medium, and Low overall outcome estimate.

To be explicit, here's how I see High/Medium/Low mapping to the 95% confidence interval, where B is the coefficient and SE is the standard error:

High = (B*X)+(1.96*SE)

Medium = (B*X)

Low = (B*X)-(1.96*SE)

Again, the High estimated outcome is the sum of all the High predictions for the input variables, the Medium outcome is the sum of all the Medium predictions, and so forth.

**The "Problem":** Some of my input variables are binary indicators (with values of 0 or 1). I'm not sure how to handle the binary indicators with values of 0 when summing the input variables to generate the High and Low predictions.

**My Question:** When a binary indicator variable equals 0, can I leave their High and Low estimates as simply 0, or do I have to use the High/Low formulas listed above [e.g., (B*0)+(1.96*SE)]? Put another way, is the prediction for a 0-value indicator variable always 0, regardless of High/Medium/Low?

**Why It Matters:** If I assume that the predictions for the 0-value binary indicators always equal 0, I get a much more accurate High/Medium/Low range of estimated outcomes. If I adhere to the formulas listed above regardless of the binary indicator's value, I get a much broader range of predictions. (This is probably because the first case basically assumes that SE=0 for 0-value binary indicators).

This problem has me puzzled, so I would be greatly appreciative of any insights. Happy to illustrate by example as well.

Comment: One problem is that you are trying to use confidence intervals where you need a prediction interval procedure. Another is that you seem not to be accounting for the error in the regression estimates. A third potentially is that you are not accounting for the possibility of correlation among the values of the profile variables. A fourth is that you seem to be conflating *accuracy* with *precision*: when you neglect sources of uncertainty you get more *precise* intervals but in fact they probably have much less coverage than you planned on, making them *less* accurate.

Comment: *whuber:* Thank you for your comments. I did some research on prediction intervals and have been able to find info on how to get intervals for a single profile variable, but not on how to use intervals to get ranges for overall estimates when there are multiple profile variables. Any ideas on resources for this?